# Python Flask "Cannot access local variable 'request'"

Tags: python, json, flask

I am currently stuck with this error where I tried to load the JSON twice by using POST method from HTML, and I encountered this error. Is there any solution to this?

```
company = json.loads(request.data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'request' where it is not associated with a value
```

This is the JS code I to FETCH the data from HTML

```
    function modifyCompany(id) {
    fetch('/profile', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ compID: id})
    }).then((_res) => {
        window.location.href = "/profile"
    })}

function matchRequest(comp_id) {
fetch('/match_request', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ requestCompID: comp_id })
}).then((_res) => {
    window.location.href = "/profile"
})}
```

These are the two codes where I used JSON loads.

first:

```
@views.route('/getCompanyID', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def companyID():
    global currentBusinessID

    company = json.loads(request.data)
    companyId = company['compID']
    company = Company.query.get(companyId)
    currentBusinessID = company

    current_company = Company.query.get(currentBusinessID.id)
    if not current_company:
        return "Company not found", 404

    current_user = User.query.get(current_company.user_id)
    if not current_user:
        return "User not found", 404

    return jsonify({}) #Returns nothing
```

second:

```
@views.route('/match_request', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def send_request():
    global currentBusinessID

    company = json.loads(request.data)
    companyId = company['requestCompID']
    company = Company.query.get(companyId)
    requestMatchCompanyID = company

    sender_id = currentBusinessID.id
    receiver_id = requestMatchCompanyID.id

    if sender_id and receiver_id:
        request = MatchRequest(sender_id=sender_id, receiver_id=receiver_id)
        db.session.add(request)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({})
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid data'}), 400
```

Comment: Last code snippet contains `request = MatchRequest...`. Rename the variable here to avoid this error.

Comment: Where is `request` defined prior to being called in both of these functions?

Comment: So I was able to fix the problem, Michael! Thank you for this one. I didn't notice that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by renaming the MatchRequest query variable. Thanks to Michael Butscher.

Before:

```
    if sender_id and receiver_id:
    request = MatchRequest(sender_id=sender_id, receiver_id=receiver_id)
    db.session.add(request)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({})
```

After:

```
    if sender_id and receiver_id:
    matchRequestQuery = MatchRequest(sender_id=sender_id, receiver_id=receiver_id)
    db.session.add(matchRequestQuery)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({})
```